# JEE6 Timer Persistence across Redeploy

Tags: timer, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

One of the tasks of the app that I'm developing is to backup the data of other applications running on the system. I want to schedule this backup process so that it can run unattended. I'm using the JEE6 / EJB3.1 Timer utilities.

I have a class BackupConfiguration which I persist to a database using JPA2 which has a field of type TimerHandle. If the user decides to schedule the backup I create a new persistent Timer and populate the TimerHandle field.

If I restart the server everything is fine, the timers restart (and there's a brief panic as all the timers fire at once, sigh) and everything is as I left it.

If I redeploy the application (which happens quite a lot while I'm developing it) all the timers are lost! I stupidly assumed that timers would be tied to the server but it turns out they are tied to the application.

So, my question, what is the best way to make timers that are persistent across re-deployment?

The only solution I can see would be to store the ScheduleExpression as well as the TimerHandle with the backup configuration. Then, if I have a handle but no Timer I recreate the timer. The main problem with this though is that it means enumerating every scheduled entity every time the application starts to find out if there are missing timers. That's not a lot of work at the moment but in future that could grow to be a huge cost.

Comment: Which application server are you using?  You're describing the behavior of WebSphere Application Server, but it's not clear.  If that's the application server you're using, then I do not believe there is an option to avoid clearing the persistent timers during redeploy unless your application server is stopped when you perform the uninstall (e.g., using a disconnected wsadmin session).

Comment: I'm using GlassFish 3.0.1, this seems to be standard behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that most (probably all) application servers make timers persistent to the application not the server. This makes sense since when you remove an application you wouldn't want the timers hanging around. It's awkward during development though because NetBeans, at least, will remove the application before re-deploying thus losing all the timers.

The solution I've come up with is to store the TimerHandle and the scheduling information in the database. When the application starts up it creates a TimerRepair singleton bean which calls repairTimers on any any classes that require it. The repairTimers method selectes all the Schedules and, if they have a TimerHandle attempts to recover the Timer. If the Timer recovery throws an exception it recreates the Timer from the scheduling information. Overall it's not too bad as a solution, my only real concern with it is excessive start up time if a lot of items are scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

For GlassFish there is `--keepstate=true` option of the `asadmin redeploy` command.

It retains EJB timers between redeployments.

For details you can see:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beahw.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggndx.html#SJSASEEAGgkudf

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/redeploy-1.html#scrolltoc