# Java EE Timer Service, programmatic timers and application deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, timer

I am using Java EE Timer Services programmatically to create persistent timers

```
@Resource
TimerService timerService;

...
timerService.createCalendarTimer( scheduleExpression, new TimerConfig( ..., true ) );
```

Timers work as expected and are persisted: I can stop and start the server and the timers are still there.

Now when I deploy a new version of the application the timers are lost. Is there a way to either:

- keep the timers when an application is re-deployed on the same server
- have a method called by the first start of my Java EE application after deployment so that I can re-create all the timers?

Comment: FYI: there was a JIRA issue created at the EJB spec that addressed exactly this, but it was rejected for unclear reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134629/2935). In short; there's no automatic way to keep timers on redeploy, and you need to handle that yourself. Perhaps recreate them on application startup using `@Startup`?